are the Knill-Laflamme conditions just a clever restatement of the no-cloning theorem?
We say that an error $E$ is correctable by a code $\mathcal C$ if there exists a recovery unitary $U$ such that
$$U(\frac{1}{\sqrt{P(E \vert \psi)}} | \psi \rangle \otimes |0^a \rangle) = |\psi \rangle \otimes |\text{syndrome}_{E \vert \psi}\rangle$$
This implies that
$$U(| \psi \rangle \otimes |0^a \rangle) = |\psi \rangle \otimes (\sqrt{P_E | \psi}|\text{syndrome}_{E \vert \psi}\rangle)$$
Now, we can see that the LHS is a linear function of $\psi$, so the the RHS must be too, which implies that $\sqrt{P_E | \psi}|\text{syndrome}_{E \vert \psi}\rangle$ is in fact independent of $\psi$. From this, one derives the Knill-Laflamme conditions by taking an inner product.
However, I noticed that this is essentially the same argument as in the no-cloning theorem. Is it correct to say that the syndrome register on the RHS is independent of $\psi$ simply because there cannot be a unitary that allows $U(|\psi\rangle|0^a\rangle) = |\psi \rangle |f(\psi)\rangle$ for a fixed $f$ and arbitrary $\psi$?

Could you elaborate on the meaning of $|0^a\rangle$ and why you put a tensor product with your logical information $|\psi\rangle$?

$|0^a\rangle$ just denotes any ancilla states that we may need use in the error detection algorithm. There is a tensor product with the logical state since a given recovery algorithm (i.e. the unitary $U$) will generally take both the logical state and the ancilla as input. (Think of how the Shor 9-qubit code needs two ancilla to diagnose, say, a Z error)

I think the relationship between no-cloning and Knill-Laflamme isn't very strong. Just to recap, the Knill-Laflamme conditions are the RHS of the following statement of equivalence
\begin{align}
(V, \mathcal{E}) \text{ is a QECC}  \Longleftrightarrow \left( E_i,E_j\in \mathcal{E} \Rightarrow PE_i E_j P = c_{ij} P\right), \tag{1}
\end{align}
where $\mathcal{E}$ is the set of correctable errors, and $V$ is an encoding isometry. $(V, \mathcal{E})$ being a QECC is defined as the existence of a decoding isometry $U$ that satisfies your first equation (modified slightly to make the error explicit):
$$U E V (|\psi\rangle \otimes |0^a\rangle) = |\psi\rangle \otimes c_{\psi,E}|s_{\psi,E}\rangle. \tag{2}
$$
Then, linearity can get Eq. (2) into a form where the ancilla/coefficient are independent of $\psi$ like you showed. But two points I would make are:

Replacing $c_{\psi,E}|s_{\psi,E}\rangle$ with $c_{E}|s_{E}\rangle$  doesn't obviously follow from no-cloning because $UEV$ isn't a valid quantum operation. $E$ can be any linear operator really, while no-cloning arguments usually apply to physical processes (e.g. CPTP maps). Arguing that a non-physical map like $E$ obeys no-cloning is similar to arguing that a nonlinear map might violate no-cloning: It may be true, but it becomes more of a mathematical statement (i.e. ``linearity'') rather than a statement about physics.
Linearity just gives "$\Rightarrow$" in Eq. (1). But the Knill-Laflamme conditions wouldn't be very useful without the "$\Leftarrow$". The proof of "$\Leftarrow$" in Eq. (1) seems unrelated to cloning (but I'm sure it also invokes linearity).

